# Summoning an armor stand with a falling sand entity riding it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm having an issue. I'm trying to summon an armor stand with a falling sand entity riding it. The armor stand will summon, but the falling sand is either invisible or not there.

Here's the command:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"falling_Sand",Time:1,Block:planks,Data:2}]}
```

This is in 1.12, and having the falling sand would make my life a whole lot easier. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Evan, if you've figured it out consider posting your solution as an answer, that way others looking for a solution to the same problem can also figure it out!

Comment: Can you then please write it as your own answer and accept that? That way this doesn't stay as an unanswered question that people might try to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Falling_Sand was changed to Falling_Block, so the command would be:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Falling_block",Time:1,Block:"minecraft:planks",Data:2}]}
```